# docker php 7.4 got AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator

Tags: php, docker

Im installing php7.4 from https://hub.docker.com/_/php but got AH00141 error. im able to install it with version 7.2 but i want to install 7.4

here's the command and response :

```
phpdocker]$ sudo docker run --rm --name PHP74_CONTAINER php:7.4-apache
[Mon Jan 24 08:26:01.105711 2022] [:crit] [pid 1] (38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
```

docker version :

> phpdocker]$ sudo docker version
> Client: Docker Engine - Community
> Version:           20.10.11
> API version:       1.41
> Go version:        go1.16.9
> Git commit:        dea9396
> Built:             Thu Nov 18 00:38:53 2021
> OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
> Context:           default
> Experimental:      true
>
> Server: Docker Engine - Community
> Engine:
> Version:          20.10.11
> API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
> Go version:       go1.16.9
> Git commit:       847da18
> Built:            Thu Nov 18 00:37:17 2021
> OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
> Experimental:     false
> containerd:
> Version:          1.4.12
> GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
> runc:
> Version:          1.0.2
> GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
> docker-init:
> Version:          0.19.0
> GitCommit:        de40ad0

docker info :

> phpdocker]$ sudo docker info
> Client:
> Context:    default
> Debug Mode: false
> Plugins:
> app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
> buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.6.3-docker)
> scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.9.0)
>
> Server:
> Containers: 4
> Running: 0
> Paused: 0
> Stopped: 4
> Images: 4
> Server Version: 20.10.11
> Storage Driver: overlay2
> Backing Filesystem: extfs
> Supports d_type: true
> Native Overlay Diff: false
> userxattr: false
> Logging Driver: json-file
> Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
> Cgroup Version: 1
> Plugins:
> Volume: local
> Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
> Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
> Swarm: inactive
> Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
> Default Runtime: runc
> Init Binary: docker-init
> containerd version: 7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
> runc version: v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
> init version: de40ad0
> Security Options:
> seccomp
> Profile: default
> Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
> Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
> OSType: linux
> Architecture: x86_64
> CPUs: 2
> Total Memory: 7.64GiB
> Name: DevWira
> ID: IRP6:5FKE:CXI6:N3OS:HQ7Y:TAKU:JZJP:UABZ:XBDH:7IJO:EWCF:AKBJ
> Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
> Debug Mode: false
> Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
> Labels:
> Experimental: false
> Insecure Registries:
> 127.0.0.0/8
> Live Restore Enabled: false

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

Comment: and your OS info?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)